Xcode asks me to download the simulator again after every update
I have updated Xcode multiple times before, and after each update, it asks me to download the simulator again. I already had the simulator installed on my computer prior to the updates. Now, there is another update available, but I am hesitant to proceed because I don't want to download the simulator again. Could you help me? (This is my first question on Stack Overflow)
I expected the simulator to remain installed after updating Xcode, as it did in some previous updates. However, after recent updates, Xcode asked me to download the simulator again, even though I didn’t delete or modify it. I checked the Xcode settings and tried restarting both Xcode and my Mac, but the issue persists. I was hoping the simulator would remain available without requiring reinstallation. I am looking for a way to avoid downloading it every time I update Xcode.

Which version of Xcode and macOS do your have? And what simulator precisely Xcode is asking you to download? Simulators and their runtimes are usually required to comply with the latest Xcode so they will get updated together with it. Unless you are talking about something else.

Until Xcode 13, all the simulators were bundled with the Xcode download and the bundle size was around 10 GB. Since Xcode 14, the simulators are not included anymore, shrinking the initial download to 7GB (Xc 14), then 3 GB (Xc 15). Xcode now asks on first launch if and which simulators you want to install.
Read more about that change here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes
So probably you were always downloading the new matching simulators, just with the new procedure you are explicitly asked for that.
